# Syntax Highlighting Guide for Atom

Tags: editor, customization, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I am very pleased with the new editor by Github. Unfortunately it isn't exactly easy to customize it. I wanted to create my own Syntax Highlighting Theme, because I am not happy with the ones available to download (at least they don't seem to do well with Java)

Now the files (syntax-variables, color.less, etc.) to style seem to be in:

```
~/.atom/ .../packages (if you want to change existing themes)
```

The problem is just that I don't know which (CSS) classes style which elements of the syntax. Is there a place where I can look up how to change the color of for example variable type declarations?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you can start Atom in Developer Mode by using the command `atom --dev` or by using the menu `View > Developer > Open in Dev Mode ...`. When you do that you can right click on any element in the UI and select `Inspect Element` from the context menu, just like you would in your web browser.

Additionally, for syntax elements you can:

1. Put your text cursor on the item you want to style
2. Press <kbd>Cmd+Alt+P</kbd> on OS X, <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P</kbd> on other platforms, or find "Editor: Log Cursor Scope" in the command palette to display the scopes of the syntax element

The scopes of the syntax element translate directly to CSS classes.

Comment: This solution ended up being very helpful with Markdown files that seems to lack decent syntax highlighting. I just put the classes directly into the styles.less under the `.editor {}` class.

Comment: Cmd+Alt+P is a Mac-specific shortcut... I tried Ctrl+Alt+P on Windows, without success... And I can't find your string in the command palette, in 1.3.1.

Comment: "Editor: Log Cursor Scope" only shows up in the Command Palette when you have your cursor in an active editor. It will show up if you do step #1 first.

Comment: Note that you may need to add a section for every style that pops up when you hit Cmd+Opt+P. If you only do one of the styles then the other one(s) may be overwriting what you're trying to do e.g. changing color

Answer (score 7):

You can use chromium web-console by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+I` (tested in linux) and highlighting any element. After then open your stylesheet by pressing `Edit->Open Your Stylesheet` and add style for element with LESS syntax.

For example:

You want bold highlighting class and function name. If you select class with chromium-console you can see that it have class `.name`

That you should add in you Stylesheet file something like this:

```
atom-text-editor::shadow .name{
    font-weight: bold
}
```

And you may create you own theme. In Atom it's not difficlt - press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type `"Generate Syntax Theme"`. In new theme you can copy some code from other theme. If you don't know CSS/LESS - don't worry! Your new theme have file in `style` folder named `colors.less`. You can change it or write new color rule on base.less file.

Atom have awesome doc, you can read about creating theme in this page https://atom.io/docs/v1.4.2/hacking-atom-creating-a-theme

Comment: Thanks I was finally able to change the comment color. The part where you show that you have to specify "atom-text-editor::shadow" is important and for some reason I haven't seen that explained or demonstrated anywhere else.

Comment: Yes the "atom-text-editor::shadow" is important , and also you may need to add a section for every style that pops up when you hit Cmd+Opt+P. If you only do one of the styles then the other one may be overwriting what you're trying to do e.g. changing color

Comment: `::shadow` is depreciated. New syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43373452/1486850

Comment: Thank you for this poin. I post this 2 years ago and honestly very suprise how long it works)

Answer (score 1):

For others that come here because the highlighting for a filetype is not recognized for your language:

- open the `~/.atom/config.cson` file (by CTRL+SHIFT+p: type ``open config'')
- add/edit a `customFileTypes` section under `core` for example like the following:

  ```
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      "source.lua": [
        "conf"
      ]
      "text.html.php": [
        "thtml"
      ]
  ```

(You find the languages scope names ("source.lua", "text.html.php"...) in the language package settings [see here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#finding-a-languages-scope-name))

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Go to Install -> search for the package -> select the package -> click install button

[image]