# Atom (editor): modify existing theme and save as a new one

Tags: atom-editor

I do not want to create the entire theme from the scratch.

1. I want to use the existing theme.
2. I want to make some minor style changes (like color) for a few elements.
3. I don't want to save the changes in the original theme but in its copy.

For example.

1. I've installed the [Bade3 Notepad](https://atom.io/themes/bade3-notepad-syntax) theme.
2. I like the notepad++'s highlighting but in find out the grey string are too light.
3. According to [Syntax Highlighting Guide for Atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963733/syntax-highlighting-guide-for-atom) [Syntax Highlighting Guide for Atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963733/syntax-highlighting-guide-for-atom) I've run Atom in Developer Mode.
4. I've opened file that contains some quoted string.
5. Right click some quoted string and select *Inspect Element*
6. In the Styles tabs I change the color value in

   .string.quoted.php {
     color: #8b8b8b;
   }
7. The changes are applied to the real example code so I can adjust color.
8. Let's say I'm fine with #107000

Now I wish to save this changes.

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve this through your personal style sheet without creating or editing a theme.

1. Your "stylesheet <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> and typing `Application: Open Your Style Sheet`.
2. A file will open in Atom that looks similar to this:

   ```
   // style the background color of the tree view
   .tree-view {
     // background-color: whitesmoke;
   }

   // style the background and foreground colors on the atom-text-editor-element itself
   atom-text-editor {
     // color: white;
     // background-color: hsl(180, 24%, 12%);
   }

   // To style other content in the text editor's shadow DOM, use the ::shadow expression
   atom-text-editor::shadow {
     // Add Your Styles Here
   }
   ```
3. In the area between `atom-text-editor::shadow {` (line 13) and the closing `}` (line 15) add you changed styles:

   ```
   .string.quoted.php { color: #8b8b8b; }
   ```
4. Save the Stylesheet and check it is working as expected in your editor, no need to reload or restart the editor.

> **Note:** if you have the `Use Shadow DOM` check box unchecked in Atom Settings, accessed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd>, then you will need to put your styles between `atom-text-editor {` (line 7) and the closing `}` (line 10).  Try and work with Atom with the Shadow DOM enabled as the option to disable it will go away in future versions.

Here is a short animation to go through the steps I took to get this to work in Atom 1.8 Beta:

[image: Atom Editor: Custom Styles]

Comment: Good to know this "Ctrl-Shift-P" magic and "Application: Open Your Style Sheet"! In recent Atom releases, the opened styles.less is empty, and all you need is to add your custom style as is.