# Atom (Editor) - how modify an existing theme, in 2021?

Tags: themes, customization, atom-editor

I see this question hasn't been asked for several years, so it's better to ask it again, because the previous solution is out of date.

I am using an **atom-material** theme, which I like very much. Except that the color of an id-attribute, in HTML, is the same as it's class-attribute. It makes it harder to read and distinguish code.

Or for example "public" and "private" are not colored purple like "variable" is.

So I wanted to ask:
Where can I modify this specific part of a (syntax)theme?

...and how would I find out which "selection handles" to use, in order to target specific elements that I want? (for example "public" for php or "id" for HTML)

Thank you.

----------------- 
This old answer uses Shadow DOM:
[Atom (editor): modify existing theme and save as a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146782/atom-editor-modify-existing-theme-and-save-as-a-new-one/36939524#36939524)

But that is no longer available:
https://flight-manual.atom.io/shadow-dom/