# Changing comment colour in Atom editor

Tags: css, atom-editor

I would like to change the colour of comments in the Atom editor. From a bit of googling, I found I can put the following in my .atom/styles.less file:

```
atom-text-editor::shadow .comment {
    color: #ffffaa;
}
```

That's great - now I have bright yellow comments that demand to be noticed rather than fading into the background. The trouble is that it now looks like the below

[image]

As you can see, the text colour of the comments has changed, but the comment delimiters and links within comments remain in the default almost-invisible-grey, which looks a bit silly.

My questions are (1) how can I change the colour of these items, and more importantly (2) where can I look up how to change the colour of these items?

Please note that I am not a web programmer and know nothing of CSS or any related technologies. I am therefore looking for a fairly step-by-step solution, in contrast to solutions found, for example, in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963733/syntax-highlighting-guide-for-atom), which assume a substantial amount of background in the inner workings of this stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax Highlighting Guide for Atom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963733/syntax-highlighting-guide-for-atom)

Comment: Though I believe this question is a duplicate, this *might* be the code you are looking for. Just add it to the file you already found. `atom-text-editor::shadow {
    .punctuation.comment, .comment, .link.hyperlink {
        color: #ffffaa;
    }
}
`

Comment: @Hexaholic the linked question is a good example of what I'm talking about in my final parenthetical. For someone versed in CSS it may well be an answer to my question, but for me it is not, because I don't have the knowledge to convert the information that cmd-alt-P gives me into the CSS code I should type. Your second comment is helpful and could be posted as an answer, but there's no way I could have deduced it from the information in the first link.

Comment: I see your point. While I'm still not convinced this is not a duplicate, I'll be posting an answer soon.

Comment: The `atom` tag you used for this question is in relation to the XML based syndication format, as this post is about GitHub's Atom Editor I have changed the tag to `atom-editor`. Hope this helps your question get the right eyes on it, for further information about tags have a read of [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To find out the CSS classes of any element you want to style, follow these steps in the editor:

1. Use your cursor to highlight the element you want to inspect. I'm following your example of a double slash (i.e. a comment) here.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on OS X). A pop-up will tell you all classes of that element. Usually, it's the last line of that notification that is of interest for us. For `//`, it is `comment.line.double-slash.js`.
3. Disregard the last dot and everything following it, since keeping it would apply your changes to a specific file type only (`js` in this case). Now prepend a dot. The remaining string is the element we want to style: `.comment.line.double-slash`.

Open the `.atom/styles.less` by opening the command pallette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on OSX) and searching for "Application: Open Your Stylesheet".

Append these lines to `.atom/styles.less`, if not already present:

```
atom-text-editor::shadow {
    // custom comment styling goes here
}
```

Inside the brackets you can place CSS/LESS code for any element you want to customize.

```
atom-text-editor::shadow {
    .comment.line.double-slash {
        color: #ffffaa;
    }
}
```

---

*Additional advice:* you can enumerate element identifiers as a comma-and-space-separated list, if the same changes should apply to them. So if you want to make links the same color as comments, there are two possibilities:

```
.comment.line.double-slash {
    color: #ffffaa;
}
.markup.underline.link.hyperlink { // I removed the '.https' to apply this to all protocols
    color: #ffffaa;
}
```

or

```
.comment.line.double-slash, .markup.underline.link.hyperlink {
    color: #ffffaa;
}
```

With long class names as they are used here, I'd prefer the first option for readability. But that's up to your choice.

Comment: Step 2 with Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P didn't work for me in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P doesn't work for me on Windows 10 either.

Comment: Since `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P` didn't work for me either (Windows 11), what is the name of the function that expands to (i.e. accessible via `Ctrl+Shift+P`)?

Answer (score 32):

Using 1.14.4:

```
// This styles comment text
atom-text-editor .syntax--comment {
    color: #53FFA1;
}

// This styles comment punctuation (i.e. //, and /*...*/)
.syntax--punctuation.syntax--definition.syntax--comment {
    color: #008C3F;
}
```

Comment: That mint green is poppin!

Answer (score 14):

The syntax is changed in 1.14.
Now, you need to use this for changing the comment color

```
atom-text-editor .syntax--comment {
         color: #228B22;
}
```

Comment: How can I change the syntax if I only want to change it for a certain file type?

Answer (score 3):

An update to @Hexaholic's now out-dated answer:

### Find the CSS class of the element you want to style

1. Launch the Developer Tools window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> (Windows; command: `window:toggle-dev-tools`)
2. Activate the Element Inspector (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from within the developer tools window, or click the cursor icon)

[image: Element inspector]

3. Hover over the element you wish to style

[image: Inspecting an element]

4. Identify the appropriate style name: each style name begins with a dot and proceeds to the next dot.  This example applies the styles `.syntax--comment`, `.syntax--block` and `.syntax--bibtex`.

### Apply custom CSS

1. Open the custom stylesheet `.atom/styles.less` ("Application: Open Your Stylesheet" in the command finder (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, OSX)
2. Enter the appropriate CSS.  For example, to colour all comments:

```css
atom-text-editor .syntax--comment {
  color: #ffffaa;
}
```

Or to colour all comments also tagged as bibtex:

```css
atom-text-editor .syntax--comment.syntax--bibtex {
  color: #ffffaa;
}
```

As usual with CSS, more specific comments (as the latter) will override more general classes (as the former).

### Further reading

- Atom's guide to [Further Customization](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/)