# How to make comments in color?

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

I am trying to get my comments to be in color. I have this inputted into styles less but this comment only works with `/* */`  I want it to work as well or instead via `//`

```html
atom-text-editor
.syntax--comment {
color: red;
}
```

I get the following:

> Error compiling Less stylesheet:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing comment colour in Atom editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37028403/changing-comment-colour-in-atom-editor)

Answer (score 0):

Atom is based upon Chromium, which is why it includes the full developer tools as you might know them from the Chrome browser. The inspector will allow you to find the selector for any element.

[image]

To differentiate between block comments and line comments, you need to use different selectors:

```
atom-text-editor {
  .syntax--comment.syntax--line {
    color: blue
  }

  .syntax--comment.syntax--block {
    color: red
  }
}
```

Or, if you want to be super strict, use the selector `.syntax--comment.syntax--line.syntax--double-slash`.